# How to use std::back_inserter to insert into a container (only have a pointer to container)

Tags: c++, stl, iterator, containers

I would like to transform from foo to bar.

```
struct A
{
    explicit A(int d): m_d(d) {};
private:
    int m_d;
};
A some_function (int i) { return A(2*i); }

std::vector<int> foo; 
std::vector<A> bar; // This is part of a Library not under my control
```

The interface only provides pbar

```
std::vector<A>* pbar =&bar; // This is the interface to the part of a Library not under my control
```

**Is it legal to dereference pbar und use it as argument for back_inserter? Why?**

```
std::transform (foo.begin(), foo.end(), std::back_inserter(*pbar), some_function);
```

A full example is here : http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/2aec8d000cabf78b

Comment: @Why is not it legal? In fact std::back_insert_iterator uses internally a pointer to the container.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, there's no problem with doing that at all. I'm not really sure what the source of your confusion is, so I'm not sure how to answer "why." If you have a non-`const` pointer to an object, you're allowed to dereference it and pass it to functions that need a non-`const` reference (like `std::back_inserter`).

Comment: My confusion arises because I was not sure if this reference is later assigned to a value and making a copy .